# How do I use grouping, distinct, and count together in linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an ActivityLog table with a row for each hit on each page in a web app.  The table has the following pertinent fields: PageTitle, UserName, ActivityDate.  I'd like to add a Usage History page with a GridView that has the following columns:  Page Title, # Hits, # Unique Users.  So for each page in the app, we would show the total number of hits, and the number of unique users hitting that page.

I have tried the following linq, which, from what I could gather in my searches, should work:

```
var ual = (from activityLog in linqMetaData.UserActivityLog
           group activityLog by activityLog.PageTitle into pageGroup
           select new PageUsageStatistics()
           {
               PageTitle = pageGroup.Key,
               NumHits = pageGroup.Count(),
               NumUniqueUsers = pageGroup.Select(x => x.UserName).Distinct().Count()
           });
```

The NumHits comes back with the expected number; however, NumUniqueUsers is coming back with the number of unique total users that have hits, not the count for each page.  So if I have 3 users, each having 1 hit on their own distinct page (User1 hits Page1, User2 hits Page2, and User3 hits Page3), all three rows in my table are showing 3 for the NumUniqueUsers column, even though they should show 1.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, 
Chris

EDIT - Adding generated SQL:

```
SELECT [LPA_L1].[PageName], 
       [LPA_L1].[NumHits], 
       [LPA_L1].[NumUniqueUsers] 
FROM 
    (SELECT [LPA_L2].[PageTitle] AS [PageName], 
            [LPA_L2].[LPAV_] AS [NumHits], 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) AS [LPAV_] 
             FROM 
                 (SELECT DISTINCT [LPA_L2].[UserPrincipleName] 
                  FROM [USIC].[dbo].[UserActivityLog]  [LPA_L2]  
                 ) [LPA_L3]) AS [NumUniqueUsers] 
     FROM 
         (SELECT [LPLA_1].[PageTitle], 
                 COUNT(*) AS [LPAV_] 
          FROM [USIC].[dbo].[UserActivityLog]  [LPLA_1]   
          GROUP BY [LPLA_1].[PageTitle]
         ) [LPA_L2]
    ) [LPA_L1] 
ORDER BY [LPA_L1].[PageName] ASC
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't see anything wrong with that code.

Comment: Haha, nor do I!  I can't figure out why it's showing 3 instead of 1 for the unique users!

Comment: Can you show us the generated sql?

Comment: I just added the generated SQL to the OP.  And it looks like it is incorrect.  Query LPA_L3 is just getting the distinct users from the entire table, instead of from the group.

Comment: LinqToSql uses [t0], [t1] ... as table aliases.  What technology are you really using to do query translation?  It appears that technology has a defect.

Comment: We are using LLBLGen 3.0, which has its own Linq provider.

Answer (score 1):

"3 users, each having 1 hit on each of 3 pages"

I interpret that as meaning your log looks like:

- User1 - Page1
- User1 - Page2
- User1 - Page3
- User2 - Page1
- User2 - Page2
- User2 - Page3
- User3 - Page1
- User3 - Page2
- User3 - Page3

With that scenario, each page does indeed have 3 unique users so your code is correct

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. What I meant was, each user has one hit on their own distinct page. So it's: User1 - Page1; User2 - Page2; User3 - Page3. I'll modify the original post.

Comment: Still, the code here seems fine.  So I would do two things... first, drop in a breakpoint and inspect pageGroup to see what it actually contains.  If it doesn't contains what you expect (3 entries, 1 per user) then the problem can be traced back to activityLog having bad data somehow.  Otherwise, the problem can be traced to Distinct not being able to correctly compare UserName values.  You can solve that by using the other overload to Distinct which lets you pass in a custom comparer.

Comment: I tried putting a breakpoint in, and it will not stop in the middle of the query; VS puts the breakpoint around the entire query, and then when you step into it, it just stops on the DataSource getter, and when you try to step into that, it skips down to past the linq query.  I can't get it to stop in the middle of the query.  Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
NumUniqueUsers = pageGroup.DistinctBy(x => x.UserName).Count();
```

Comment: Are you saying that this can't be used with LINQ to SQL?

Comment: There's no way to put "new HashSet<TKey>()" into the database.  Methods that are compiled by .NET can't be translated to sql - only expression trees can, and then only certain expression trees.

Comment: But OP only wants to get the number of distinct users... this wouldn't work for that?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say where that DISTINCT is getting lost.  Perhaps LinqToSql is dropping it in query translation.  Looking at the generated sql will confirm.

If the Distinct is getting (unexpectedly) dropped by LinqToSql, here's another way to write that part of the query.

```
NumUniqueUsers = pageGroup.GroupBy(x => x.UserName).Count()
```

Comment: I tried this, and got "Unable to cast object of type 'SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionClasses.QueryExpression' to type 'SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionClasses.SetReferenceExpression'."

Comment: Now that I've added the generated SQL, it looks like the Distinct is not getting lost, but it is applying to the entire table, instead of the grouped section.